# Wrapping -- don't break up paragraphs

Tags: css, css-float

I have a pretty standard page layout where there's an image floated to the left, and then some information to the right of it, that consists of 1 line headers (bold) and 1 line of data underneath each header.

I want the data to flow around the image, but is there any way I can stop the data from breaking from the header that goes with it when it wraps? I.E. only wrap between a line of data and the next header.

Seems simple, but I haven't been able to come up with a way to do it!

Edit: here is a jsfiddle to illustrate my situation (cool site!): http://www.jsfiddle.net/qYcX5/
See the last paragraph is broken apart from its header.

BTW, on the actual page I'm building, the length of paragraphs on the right and the # of items will vary, so I can't arbitrarily decide to clear the data at a certain point and always have it look right.

Comment: could you post some code and and/or a link to a working example??? Or even better a http://www.jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: Could you post a simple sketch showing what you have and another one showing what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added the jsfiddle link. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but so the answer's out there...

I think the easiest way to do this would be to wrap the header/paragraph pairs in a div or section element and then set them to overflow:hidden -

```css
div#parent-block {
  width: 600px
}

div#parent-block img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  font-weight:bold;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200">
  <section>
    <h3>A header</h3>
    <p>Some text that should stay with its header</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A header</h3>
    <p>Some text that should stay with its header</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A header</h3>
    <p>Some text that should stay with its header</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A header</h3>
    <p>Some text that should stay with its header</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A header</h3>
    <p>Some text that should stay with its header</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrbh/cyjvspLs/2/

Comment: amazing, it works! 5 years later, you win the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this HTML - http://textsnip.com/1022ae and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Not quite, but thanks for the effort -- it seemed to work on your example, but I couldn't get it to work on the example I posted above..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravikiranj/myYeu/ -> Can you check this, is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: no, but thanks again for trying. the text in your example doesn't wrap around the image..

Comment: sorry, i might have misunderstood your question. if there is no way to check how many items show up on the right side and the height of the image, I dont know how one could solve the issue. I mean unless you have some clue about either left or right side you can't do that. However if you do, you check the clientHeight property and can insert a deliberating margin-bottom to push the heading also below, so that heading-text remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to integrate javascript to measure the height of your accumulated `<h3>` tags and then if they're cumulatively larger than the height of the image, `clear: left` the last one... Not sure though.

@Jessica: If you wanted all of the text on the right side, simply add the following to your CSS:

`h3, p { padding-left: 360px; /* the width of the image + 10px for extra padding */ }`

Also, check out the updated jsFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qYcX5/ for example of how this works.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely a possibility, although if it's going to require much overhead, then probably not worth it. I'll think about it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to pop a containing div around the heading and following paragraph, then float this div container.

```
<img />
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, that was the first thing i tried. the h1 and p were still separating when they wrapped.

Comment: You need to float the containing div too.

Comment: I don't think this is what Jessica was going for. If it is, I totally misunderstood. I thought she wanted the text to wrap, but she didn't want `<h3>` tags to break from their subsequent `<p>` tags. Jessica, if you want all of the text to the right of the image, there are SO many ways to do it. @Alan's way is one of them, another is to give the `<p> and <h3>` tags left-padding. etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? http://jsfiddle.net/qYcX5/18/

Comment: None of the paragraphs wrap to the next line if you decrease the width of the window or parent box. I want them to wrap around the image, but just not break from the headers.

Comment: do you know with and height of the image everytime or does that change too (meaning that you might want a different sized image to work on the same layout)?

Comment: I am pretty sure the image will always be the same width/height.